# JavaScript: recreate/order Document Fragment. Remove formatting from fragment

Tags: javascript, dom, formatting, nodes

I am building a block-based editor but have hit a wall on how to proceed.

I do not want to use `execCommand` to do things such as bold text because I want my editor to be able to wrap selected text in anything custom, as well as because `execCommand` works differently across browsers.

My issue is *undoing* fragmented markup.

For example, if we have text like this.

```
Lorem Ipsum <strong>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem</strong> Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
```

and wanted to simply unbold a word or two, that's easy.

But what if we have something like this where formatting is nested:

```
The Lost City of Atlantis is a myth and legend that has fascinated <strong>generations and captured the <mark>imagination for countless <em>storytellers since</em> the great philosopher</mark> Plato first</strong> introduced it to the masses ~360BC.
```

and I wanted to unbold the word `countless`?

Assuming I already have a created document fragment that contains all of the current nodes, and added a class `selectionNode` to the node that contains the text we want to unbold, what is the best way to go about unraveling everything to get the desired output?

[image: Document Fragment tree]

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Or am I doing this the "hard" way and there is a better solution to this all together?

Comment: Why are you mixing content with presentation? Use CSS. Wrap your block in `<span>` with appropriate class(es).

Comment: @PM77-1 
for this example, I don't care about the style as it has nothing to do with my goal. What I do care about is getting the elements to nest correctly when trying to remove part of a fragment from the markup, like my example above.